# Getting error in array, unused arguments in R

Tags: arrays, r

Unable to solve this problem, i'm having with making an array in R. R displays an array error.

When you do 
mat2 <- array(1:12, dim=c(4,3))
mat2, R works and it displays the code, however when, I do:
a <- array(8,1,2,5,9,2,9,1, dim=c(2,4), R doesn't work!

```
a <- array(8,2,9,9,1,5,2,1, dim=c(2,4))
a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `array` should be a vector. In R you can create vectors with `c()`. So you wanted:

```
a <- array(c(8,2,9,9,1,5,2,1), dim=c(2,4))
```

When you call a function like `array`, each argument is separated by a comma (with some mild caveats in the case of special arguments like `...`). That means that when you write `array(8,2,9,9,1,5,2,1, dim=c(2,4))` R doesn't see one set of numbers that should be taken together. It sees you trying to pass eight different arguments to the function `array`, and it gets understandably confused.

In the case of 2D arrays, it is typically best to use `matrix` instead, which includes a `byrow` argument to control whether the data is filled by row or by column. Typically you would only use `array` for multidimensional arrays where that distinction isn't as sensible. So it sounds like what you actually want in this case is:

```
matrix(c(8,2,9,9,1,5,2,1),nrow = 2,ncol = 4,byrow = TRUE)
```